# How to Convert String to another String format

Tags: java, string, algorithm, substring

How can I convert a string in the form `eyesOfTheTiger` to one that reads `eyes-of-the-tiger`?

Comment: Really, you should try to find this out by yourself. Read the javadoc of String and Character. At least show that you thought about a possible solution.

Comment: See string class API and use substring method

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17046827/replace-with-capital-letters

Comment: @austin It's not a duplicate. This question is in a reverse order.

Answer (score 3):

Just travel through the string and take different action if the character is uppercase.

```
public class Test {
    private static String upperCaseToDash(String input) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
            char c = input.charAt(i);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(c))
                sb.append('-').append(Character.toLowerCase(c));
            else
                sb.append(c);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(upperCaseToDash("eyesOfTheTiger"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly my implementation. +1.

Answer (score 1):

You can [split()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) the String using a regex , like `"(?<!(^|[A-Z0-9]))(?=[A-Z0-9])|(?<!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])"` and then append `-` at the end of each split .

```
public String camelCaseToDashSeparated(String initialString) {
    if(initialString==null || initialString.length()<1)
        return initialString;
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    for (String w : "eyesOfTheTiger".split("(?<!(^|[A-Z0-9]))(?=[A-Z0-9])|(?<!^)(?=[A-Z][a-z])")) {
         str.append(w.toLowerCase()+"-");
    }
    return str.substring(0, str.length()-1);
}
```

Another way would be :

Travel through the `String` , `char`  by `char` , keep adding the characters to the `StringBuilder`. Once you find a `char` in uppercase , append `-` to the `StringBuilder` with the lowercase of the `char`.

```
public  static String camelCaseToDashSeparated2 (String initialString) {
    StringBuffer buff = new StringBuffer();  
    for(int x = 0; x < initialString.length(); x++) {  
      char c = initialString.charAt(x);  
      if(Character.isUpperCase(c)) {  
        buff.append("-").append(Character.toLowerCase(c));  
      } 
      else {  
        buff.append(c);  
      }  
    }  
    return buff.toString(); 
}
```

Comment: Oh my God. It would take more space to document how this regexp works than to write the code without a regexp (and it would of course be a whole lot less efficient)

Comment: @JBNizet Absolutely , but it was my first instinct when I saw the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Before you start implementing this function yourself via substrings, regex, etc, consider using Google Guava. Class [`com.google.common.base.CaseFormat`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html) solves *exactly* what you intend to do.

In your case you need the [`LOWER_CAMEL`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html#LOWER_CAMEL) and [`LOWER_HYPHEN`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html#LOWER_HYPHEN) class constants and the [`to(CaseFormat format, String s)`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r46/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/CaseFormat.html#to%28com.google.common.base.CaseFormat,%20java.lang.String%29) method.

IMO, it's always better to use a mature and well-tested library than to implement everything yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty solution could be something like this:
(you should decide what to do with spaces, dashes, full stops, 
languages other than English etc.)

```
public static String toDashed(String value) {
    if (null == value)
        return null;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < value.length(); ++i) {
        char ch = value.charAt(i);

        if ((ch >= 'A') && (ch <= 'Z') && (i > 0)) {
            sb.append('-');
            sb.append(Character.toLowerCase(ch));
        }
        else
            sb.append(ch);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```